# Difference between MemoryConstrianedCacheManager and EhCacheManager

Tags: shiro, java-security, security-framework

I have more than two web applications deployed in tomcat. One of the application used apache shiro for session management . I need to get the session ID from the 1st application and use it in my other applications.

For Example

1st Application example uses **MemoryConstrainedCacheManager**

**Shiro.ini**

```
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager
```

For 2st Application , if i use the same configuration of 1st

```
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager
```

SSO session management is not working. I need to login again .

If i use EhcacheManager in both the application by configuring cache in xml its working,

```
ssoCacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager 
ssoCacheManager.cacheManagerConfigFile = classpath:ehcache.xml
securityManager.cacheManager = $ssoCacheManager
```

What is the difference between MemoryConstrained and EHCache manager ? Can i use memory constrained cache manager to store the session ID in tomcat container and use it in other web applications.

Answer (score 0):

[EHCache](http://www.ehcache.org/) has a lot of features, take a look at the site. The MemoryConstrainedCacheManager is basically just a cache backed by a limited size Map.